# Can Blender Alembic Export Out Animated Lines (Point and Edge, no Poly Face)?

Tags: sverchok, alembic

I am trying to export (bake) out animated lines mesh that I generated using Sverchok using Blender Alembic.

[image: bunch of lines]

When imported the Alembic back, all I got back is points. Is this Blender known Alembic limitation or Alembic in general does not like Edges?

[image: only bunch of points]

Thanks!